# Get the next record using sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, sequelize.js

Do you know if there is an easy way to get the next record using sequelize?
I return an object and I'd like to make a second query getting the next object. If it doesn't exist then probably I should create a raw query.

Edit:

my question maybe has been misunderstood. I have asked if it is possible to get the next record in the database.

For example if we have this table

```
1 foo
2 bar
3 foobar
4 barfoo
5 ...
```

and I get the first element then I would like to make a query where I get the next element that would be the second record in the database

Answer (score 0):

For use other querys you need to use callback.

Follow this example:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM foo";
sequelize.query(query, {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
         }).success(function (query1) {
            done = _.after(query1.length, function () {
               callback(query1)
            })

query = "SELECT * FROM foo2";
sequelize.query(query, {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    }).success(function (query2) {
        console.log(query1);
        console.log(query2);
    });
 });
```

This way it's possible to realize multiples querys.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of sequelize you are using. There is QueryChainer in 1.7: 
http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/1.7.0/docs/utils/

but from 2.1.0:

> [DEPRECATED] The query-chainer is deprecated and will be removed in
>   version 2.2. Please use promises instead.

So you can use raw query or make some recursive function:

```
var queries = ['SELECT ...', 'SELECT ...', ...];
var ql = queries.length();
var i = 0;

function doSomethingWithResult(result)
{
    // 
};

function executeQuery(result)
{
    if(result)
        doSomethingWithResult(result)

    if(i < ql){
        sequelize.query(queries[i]).spread(executeQuery);
        i += 1;
    }
}

executeQuery();
```